# Run forever task as root in init.d script on startup

Tags: raspbian, server, permissions, init.d

I'm trying to start a nodeJS Server on Raspbian on startup.

Everything works fine with this script:

```
#!/bin/sh
#/etc/init.d/myService
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          myService
# Required-Start:    $all
# Required-Stop:
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:
# Short-Description: your description here
### END INIT INFO
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
export NODE_PATH=$NODE_PATH:/usr/local/lib/node_modules

case "$1" in
start)
exec forever --sourceDir=/root/CamSlider -l forever.log -o out.log -e err.log -p /root/CamSlider server.js  #scriptarguments
;;
stop)
exec forever stop --sourceDir=/root/CamSliderr server.js
;;
*)
echo "Usage: /etc/init.d/myService {start|stop}"
exit 1
;;
esac
exit 0
```

This works fine. But somehow I get strange errors if my server gets started like this as oposed to a manual start within the shell as root with simply `node server.js`.

What could cause these problems? Do I need to start `myService` as root or do I need to run `forever` as root?

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Raspbian is not Ubuntu. And Raspian uses systemd instead of sysvinit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since version 8 (Jessie) Debian has switched to the new init system **systemd**. All Debian flavors, including Ubuntu and Raspbian, followed this. So old style init system **SysV** is deprecated and no more available. Its init scripts in `/etc/init.d/` are only emulated by **systemd** for downstream [Compatibility with SysV](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/Incompatibilities/). But the last sentence in the document notes:

> Note that there are some areas where systemd currently provides a certain amount of compatibility where we expect this compatibility to be removed eventually.

It seems this becomes more and more true. I suggest that you don't take more effort into fixing an emulated deprecated init system **SysV**. You should use a systemd Unit file to make your service.

Comment: Exactly what I did and its now working better! Thanks for your advice!