# Starting Real VNC daemon automatically with a boot or reboot

Tags: vnc, init.d

I can use `sudo vncserver-x11-serviced &` to start a VNC Server as a daemon.

I need to execute this command whenever I boot or reboot Raspberry Pi.

From https://www.realvnc.com/en/connect/docs/man/vncserver-x11-serviced.html, I learned that `sudo update-rc.d vncserver-x11-serviced defaults` is the command.

However, `vncserver-x11-serviced` is in `/usr/bin`, so I made a symbolic link in `/etc/init.d` with `sudo ln -s /usr/bin/vncserver-x11-serviced /init.d/vncserver-x11-serviced`

Then, I executed `sudo update-rc.d vncserver-x11-serviced defaults` as is written in the webpage.

However, when I try to access the Raspberry Pi RealVNC server using RealVNC Viewer, I have the error message.

What might be wrong?

[image: error message]

Comment: Which OS/Distro do you use? Raspbian uses systemd, so you may be using the wrong command. The correct one for Raspbian starts with `sudo systemctl enable ...` as listed on the RealVNC web page you link to.

Comment: @Dirk: I use Raspibian, I thought it's Debian based (from the book Raspberry Pi Cookbook). So, I tried update-rc.d.

Comment: Debian also uses systemd (starting with Jessie). You're apparently using outdated information...

Comment: If you are using Raspbian just enable in raspi-config

Comment: You should not use scripts in `/etc/init.d/` anymore: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/101852/79866

Answer (score 1):

`sudo systemctl start vncserver-x11-serviced.service` solved this issue. I downloaded VNCReal server without knowing Raspberry Pi already has it. Reinstallation of Raspibian and execution of the `systemctl` solved this issue.

I found that `sudo raspi-config` has `interfacing options' to turn on VNC too. https://www.realvnc.com/en/connect/docs/raspberry-pi.html